# Same user has role ADMIN in both clients X and Y but not in client Z - How to handle it in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Please do you know how to use Spring Security to handle this scenario on which I can have a number of clients, with a number of branches and a number of users with different permissions in each client and branch, example:

[image: example]

Comment: why not define several types of admins?

Comment: could you elaborate please ? I don't understand how it would work with several types of admins.

Comment: by the way, we might have N number of clients, they can sign up at the website at any time

Comment: well, Role ADMIN is just a name that you define, and you also define what endpoints or methods that this role can access. So I would just define like AdminA who can access endpoint /foo and there he could only execute some methods and AdminB would only be able to execute some other methods on endpoint /bar. Also with thymeleaf or in controller methods you could check who is logged in and depending on the user present different versions of the webpage with different methods available